# How to take away a value from an int? C#

Tags: c#, random, int

The problem is on line 3, I need to take away a number between 1-3 and save the value so more can be taken away.

```
Random randomhit = new Random();
int randomNumberhit = randomhit.Next(1, 4);
int life = life - randomNumberhit;
Console.WriteLine(life);
```

Any ideas? Am I doing it completely wrong?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Let's say your `randomNumberhit` was 5, what's the `life` printed?

Comment: What is the issue?  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Do you intend to redeclare `life` as you have done?

Comment: When the program starts it states - life is 12 - It says that the second life "...= life - ra..." - "Use of unassigned local variable 'life' "

Answer (score 4):

You're declaring the variable `life` and assigning it a value of `life - randomhit`. How can you know the result of the calculation if `life` doesn't yet have a value?

Try something like this:

```
int life = 100;
...
Random randomhit = new Random();
int randomNumberhit = randomhit.Next(1, 4);
life = life - randomNumberhit;
Console.WriteLine(life);
```

However, you may want to make `life` class variable instead. Something like this would work:

```
public class MyGuy
{

    public int Life { get; set; }

    public MyGuy()
    {
        this.Life = 100; // starting life
    }

    public void Hit()
    {
        Random randomhit = new Random();
        int randomNumberhit = randomhit.Next(1, 4);
        this.Life -= randomNumberhit;
        Console.WriteLine(this.Life);
    }
}
```

Comment: @LinkMartin If it's working for you then please select the answer as accepted. This currently look like an unanswered question.

Answer (score 2):

life need to be initalized to something

```
int life = 100; //Or some other value
Random randomhit = new Random();
int randomNumberhit = randomhit.Next(1, 4);
life = life - randomNumberhit;
Console.WriteLine(life);
```

Also note that when life is reassigned (`life = life - randomNumberhit;`) the int is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `life-randomNumberhit`, but at that point your variable `life` does not exist yet. You should initialize your `life` variable to whatever value you want:

```
Random randomhit = new Random();
int randomNumberhit = randomhit.Next(1, 4);
int life = 0; // for instance, 0
Console.WriteLine(life - randomNumberhit);
```

Comment: This does not save the new life value back into the life variable.